# Unpack error when trying to read 5 columns from TSV row

Tags: python, csv

I have a TSV file containing rows with 5 columns.  I want to write each row's columns to lines in a separate file. The first column is the filename.  I tried the code below but get the following error.

```
  filename, text, missspellings, uncertainty, weekgoal = row
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

```
import csv
import sys

csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)

with open("id_descr.tsv") as f:
    reader     = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    fieldnames = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        filename, text, missspellings, uncertainty, weekgoal = row
        print('filename: {}'.format(filename))
        print('text: {}'.format(text))
        print('missspellings: {}'.format(missspellings))
        print('uncertainty: {}'.format(uncertainty))
        print('weekgoal: {}'.format(week goal))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's at least one row with fewer than 5 columns.  Rather than assigning each column to a variable, just write out whatever columns you do get.  Rather than printing the values, write them to files based on the filename in the first column.  You can use the fieldnames read from the header rather than writing them out again.

```
data_columns = next(reader)[1:]  # skip first column header, the filename

for row in reader:
    if not row:
        continue  # need at least filename

    with open(row[0], 'w') as out:  # make separate files
        for name, value in zip(data_columns, row[1:]):  # write columns except filename
            out.write('{}: {}'.format(name, value))
```